# Gridview, convert text cells to buttons in Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I have a gridview, which have data from a SQL database. The database conaints jobs that a group need to work with. On my last column it says if it's finished or not. If its done, it will show a dateTime for when its finished, but if its not, the database contains 0 for this cell, and need a Button, that can make it finished, when it is.

Therefor the code first retrive data from the database, then i want to use RowDataBound to check if i need to show a Button, instead of the text from database. I also need an event for this button, so i can update the database with, an dateTime when finished.

Here's the code for my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="OverviewPlannedJobs" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        onrowcommand="Gridview1_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        Width="631px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="week" HeaderText="Uke" SortExpression="week">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dayNumb" HeaderText="Dag" 
            SortExpression="dayNumb">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="oven" HeaderText="Ovn" 
            SortExpression="oven">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="section" HeaderText="Seksjon" 
            SortExpression="section">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pit" HeaderText="Pit" SortExpression="pit">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="job" HeaderText="Jobb" 
            SortExpression="job">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="priority" HeaderText="Prioritet" 
            SortExpression="priority">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="timeEdited" HeaderText="Lagt til eller endret" 
            SortExpression="timeEdited" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="editts" HeaderText="Valg" 
            Text="Rediger">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:ButtonField>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="delete" Text="Slett">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:ButtonField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fullført?" SortExpression="finished">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("finished") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

then i have this rowdatabound function in code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        //Make button where finished equals zero
        if (e.Row.Cells[11].Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            //insert button
        }

    }
```

Comment: You may find it easier to create a template field, put a button in it already, and then toggle the Visible attribute of that button based on the text value.

Otherwise wiring up events and handling viewstate may be a bit of a nightmare with dynamically added buttons.

Comment: @Ruben Ravnå I can not understand what is your actual problem. You are solving your problem by using RowDataBound Event. And what is your problem actually. What do you need

Comment: Well if i have ten rows, maybe number 3,5,8 and 10 are finished rows. Then i want those to show a datetime in the eleventh column. But the rest, i want a button where they can click when the job is finished, and will then update the database with time and date for finishing the job.

Comment: Okay JcFx, can i bound a button field to a database column. So when the button is not visible, the text from database will be shown?

Comment: @RubenRavnå: You can check my answer, i think its almost clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have tested

**Code Behind:**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
            string value0 = row[3].ToString();
            if (value0 == "0")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "";
                Button btn=new Button();
                btn.Text="finish";
                e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvBind();
    }
    public void gvBind()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dap=new SqlDataAdapter("select id,name,job,status from myTable",con);
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

**Defautl.aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label ID="l1"   Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job">
                <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label id="l2" Text='<%# Bind("job") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
           <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:Label ID="l3" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**ScreenShot**:
[image]

Mark answer if it help :)

Comment: Very nice, and thanks a lot :D this was something like a solution a was working on right now, but this was a very good example :D

Comment: I'm sorry, its not working for me. Can't figure out why, but get error at one of these

Comment: @RubenRavnå: i my example i have `four column(id,name,job,status)` so `string value0 = row[3].ToString();`  mean row[3] ie(status), coz it always starts with 0,1,2,3.----  You have to make changes in it as per your column position

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, its not working for me. Can't figure out why, but get error at one of these

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string value0 = row[3].ToString();
```

i don't have an own databinding method since i've used the configure datasource for the gridview.

Think i will try to make an button itemtemplate, and then change the text, or disable button depending on the database result.